# Embedded if statement in a #define macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I was reading an article where #define macro was made like this:

```
#define TEST(level) if (level > 2) ; else std::cout
```

which then could be used in the code like this:

```
Test(1) << 3;
Test(3) << 4;
```

I was under the impression that if you wrote

```
TEST(1)
```

it would replace it with:

```
std::cout
```

and

```
TEST(3)
```

would be replaced with an empty string (in the code file). However, if it worked this way, then it should throw an error, since

```
<< 3;
```

is invalid.

How does this macro actually work? and how does the pre-processor change

```
TEST(3) << 3;
```

so that it doesn't output anything (that is, the code doesn't run)

Comment: Preprocessor is text replacement. The whole if-else is substituted in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you got it wrong:

For `TEST(3) << 3`, the replaced form is:

```
if (3 > 2) ; else std::cout << 3
```

It is still a valid expression

Answer (score 1):

It's replacing `TEST(x)` with;

```
 if (x > 2)
    // do nothing
 else
    std::cout << x
```

The preprocessor replaces all of the text, meaning you get the entire if-else

This may as well be written as

```
#define TEST(x) if (!x > 2) std::cout
```

Comment: The macro doesn't include `<< x`

Comment: True, that was dumb of me. Editing.